# How to add filter functionality?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

For example I have 4 dropdown lists in my html page.

```
DDL1 - OrgType
DDL2 - Region
DDL3 - Category
DDL4 - Sector
```

Now how can I able to query to the database and search for 1 DDL? To make myself clear here's the scenario

```
Select * 
from table1 
where OrgTypeId = 1 
  AND RegionId = 1 
  AND CategId = 1 
  AND SectorId = 1
```

Now what if I only want to search for the sector having sectorId = 1? and the other DDL can be have any value?

Comment: You tagged this with both SQL Server and MySQL, what database are you using?

Comment: Im sorry,,, Im using mysql

Comment: You'd need to dynamically build your WHERE clause to include only the fields where a value was selected in the dropdown, or at least hack up the where clauses so "unused" fields always evaluate to true.

Comment: @MarcB Im sorry I dont get it...can you give me an example?thanks

Comment: `if (org value selected in form) { add org value to query }` and the same for each of the other fields. if a field's not selected, then it simply doesn't appear in the `WHERE`.

Comment: Seems relevant to include the code that is generating the where requirement.

Comment: A SP will be your way to go. Are you using ajax on your JSPs to communicate with your server ?
In other words are these drop downs dynamically populated and are on a single page ?

Answer (score 0):

Only include the criteria you want in the `WHERE` clause. You can do that by either building the query dynamically and only inserting criteria when you need them, or setting them to something like `LIKE '%'` or `IS NOT NULL` or something that will always return true depending on your schema.

Examples:

```
--Removing unnecessary criteria
Select * 
from table1 
where SectorId = 1

--Making unused criteria always evaluate to true
Select * 
from table1 
where OrgTypeId >= 0 
  AND RegionId >= 0
  AND CategId >= 0 
  AND SectorId = 1
```

The second example above assumes that your values are all `ints`, and that they're never null, but it can be adapted to most any situation.

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: ah ok...But those values are the values of my dropdown lists. How can i able to assign >=0 value as the value of my ddl?

Comment: That all depends on how you're building your query in the first place. Is it dynamic SQL? A stored procedure?

Comment: But how are you building that code and getting the values passed from your dropdowns into your SQL statement?

Comment: I actually building a JSP web application...Im passing the value of the ddl like this select * from table where id = ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25706/discussion-between-jeff-rosenberg-and-peters)